# Serving a different client on mobile

Tags: mobile, meteor

Is it possible to serve a different set of client side code to the client if they are on a mobile device? I would like to offer a mobile optimized experience with my meteor app but i see no way to change the experience other than css selectors or large if/else statements in my handlebars templates, which feels very sloppy, as mobile and desktop templates and code are being served to both clients.

Is there some way that I could coax meteor into serving a different set of code to mobile clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor is very picky about sending everything to the client, so I didn't come up with any way to prevent the client from receiving all of the templates from the server.  However, I did build a package to simplify the process of displaying different templates to different clients.

It's called [device-detection](https://github.com/Mystor/meteor-device-detection), and is avaliable on atmosphere (`mrt add device-detection`).

I've documented it on the GitHub page.